# Best way to write functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm taking a code academy course on Javascript.

Code Academy writes functions in two different ways. Which one is more advantageous?

In the more basic lessons, they wrote functions like this:

```
var list = function() {

};
```

Then in more advanced lessons, we wrote functions like this:

```
function list() {

}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas there is small difference

Comment: @DavidThomas - That's a bit of a risky statement... try invoking a function expression before the assignment occurs.

Comment: There are **many many** similar questions on this site.  Please check out some of those rather than asking the same thing..... _again_.

Comment: @James: I take your point (and original comment deleted), but it matters only under very limited circumstances and, honestly, it's never really caused me (ymmv, obviously) any troubles so long as I remember what I'm doing.